# Reverse swiping direction in ViewPager

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, kotlin, android-viewpager

is there any possible way to change the swiping of a fragments from left to right?
 my Fragments swipes from right to left but I need the fragments to swipe from left to right.

Pager Adapter.kt

```
class pageradapter (fm: FragmentManager) : FragmentStatePagerAdapter(fm){
override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment {
    when(position){
        0-> return fragment1()
        1-> return fragment2()
        else-> return fragment3()
    }
}

override fun getCount(): Int {
    return 3
}
```

fragment1.kt  // 2 and 3 has the same code

```
class fragment1 : Fragment() {


override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                          savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1, container, false)
}
```

Main4Activity.kt

```
class Main4Activity : AppCompatActivity(){

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main4)

    val adapter = pageradapter(supportFragmentManager)
    val pager = findViewById<View>(R.id.pager) as ViewPager
    pager.adapter = adapter

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should reverse the `Fragment` positions like following:

**In PagerAdapter.kt**

```
class pageradapter (fm: FragmentManager) : FragmentStatePagerAdapter(fm){
     override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment {
         when(rotatePosition(position)) {
             0-> return fragment1()
             1-> return fragment2()
             else-> return fragment3()
         }
     }

    override fun getCount(): Int {
        return 3
    }

    private fun rotatePosition(position: Int): Int {
        return (getCount() - 1) - position
    }
}
```

**In Main4Activity**:

```
class Main4Activity : AppCompatActivity(){

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main4)

        val adapter = pageradapter(supportFragmentManager)
        val pager = findViewById<View>(R.id.pager) as ViewPager
        pager.adapter = adapter
        // setting new start position
        pager.setCurrentItem(adapter.rotatePosition(0), false);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can animate it using a [PageTransformer](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html#pagetransformer)

Or,

if you want the animation on replacing a fragment, you can set a custom animation on the `FragmentTransaction`